# Intersystems Cache - Get started with Callin API

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems

I want to develop C client code using the callin API.

I wrote code to connect to Cache. However, when I invoke it, I get ...

```
Instance is not running
Start status = -1
```

I am guessing that I am missing an environment variable to identify my default Cache instance, but I cannot find a reference to that in the Cache documentation.

I have a Suse based installation. I can start csession using "csession CACHE" in the same shell.

Any help?

Code is below....

```
static void *
mstart(void) {
    int status = 0;
    if (! gInitialised) {
        CACHE_ASTR prinp, prout, exename;

        prinp.len = prout.len = 0;
        prinp.str[0] = prout.str[0] = '\0';
        strcpy((char *)exename.str, "vavista.cache");
        exename.len = strlen((const char *)exename.str);

        status = CacheSecureStartA(
            NULL,                             /* User */
            NULL,                             /* Password */
            &exename,                          /* Application Id */
            CACHE_PROGMODE | CACHE_TTNEVER,   /* Flags */
            0,                                /* timeout */
            &prinp,                        /* Principal input device */
            &prout);                       /* Principal output device */
        printf("Start status = %d\n", status);
        atexit(mstop);
    }
    return (void *)1; /* Success */
}
```

Comment: I worked this out. I need to set the Cache Directory before starting...

    CacheSetDir("/opt/cache/mgr");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the Cache Directory before starting... CacheSetDir("/opt/cache/mgr");